# Fetching objects from core data entity retrieves wrong object

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5

I have this entity class to retrieve an object by its `id`. If the object is not found, then created one and return.

```
  static var request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String(describing: Self.self))
    request.returnsDistinctResults = true
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true
    return request
  }

 class func readObjectWith(id:String,
                             createIfNotFound:Bool = false,
                             context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Object? {
    
    // search for the object
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(id)")
    request.predicate = predicate
    
    do {
      guard let result = try context.fetch(request) as? [Object],
            result.count > 0,
            let item = result.first
      else {
        if createIfNotFound == false { return nil }

        print("new item")
        return Object(context: context)
      }
      // item exists, return
      return item
    } catch {
      return nil
    }
  }
```

I remove all objects from core data. I run this in a loop. Every time the loop iterates, this is called with a different `id` and `createIfNotFound = true`. The "new item" part will just run the first time. All other times the first object created will be returned, and that object's id, has nothing to do with the `id` passed to the method.

why?

Comment: Is `Patient` a subclass of `Object` ?

Comment: that was an error. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're creating a fetch request per loop. The `fetch` var is a static property that initialises once. It's a single-shot object and is returning the results of the first time it fired.

You can do this by changing:

`static var request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`

to

`static func freshRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`

Also you probably want to set the `id` on the new `Patient` object before returning it.

```
let patient =  Patient(context: context)
patient.id = id
return patient
```